# Jquery Buggy Slide Down in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I have simple code for Sliding Up/Down animation for my menu:

```
function animateMenuDropdown() {

j('ul.jnav li').hover(function() {

//Let's check if "jsub-menu" Class is here  
if( j(this).children('ul:first').hasClass('jsub-menu') ) {
    return false;//If it is ("jsub-menu" here) don't SlideDown...
}

    else {//Else slide down if no class

    j(this).find('ul.sub-menu:first').not(':visible').stop().slideDown(500);

    }

    },function() {//Unhover callback

var that = j(this);

j(this).find('ul.sub-menu:first').stop().slideUp(500,function(){

j(this).removeAttr('style');
});


});

}
```

It works and is sliding Up/Down as expected , but in Firefox my menu is blinking/flashing while animating when I use slideDown(). Try to hover couple of times and you will see the problem.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawymfwu/)

If I use animate function instead blinking/flashing is gone in Firefox

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s36sza2/)

So how can I fix Flicker in Firefox when I use slideDown() in Jquery without using animate()?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in my version of Firefox (36 on windows 8.1). It might simply be a video card issue on your computer. Do you have the capability to test it on a different machine?

Comment: Hm  strange... I have HD integrated chip only on my rig didn't thought it could be the issue, but yeah i will check it on other machines...

Comment: Even the best graphics cards need updated drivers sometimes. Maybe just check to make sure you have the latest ones.

Comment: Hey buddy can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it? I have updated my driver and it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can often be caused by out of date video card drivers.  Updating to the latest drivers may solve the problem. I was not able to reproduce this error with your example, indicating it may simply be your computer.